What is the openssl password salt and payload encoding schemes?
In passwords hashed with openssl, the salt and payload use an encoding. It does not look like base64, I wonder what it is.
$ 5 $ m/JgmIcrJRALRjQ5 $ XlNc5yDQITL48hPQ64ejZOJ6ChZnPiCxz2Q2GJyofC8
      salt ^^            hash ^^

My use case is that I have a byte string (actually base64) of the salt and hashes and I want to convert that to openssl format to add compatibility with another app.

It does not look like base64 - It contains only characters from the Base64 character set, so why it doesn't look like Base64 to you? (Btw., not my downvote)

It sometimes contains non base64 characters like . and never contains the padding character =

/ (and also +) are valid Base64 characters. The salt is 16 characters long, so it doesn't need padding. The only valid point is that the hash (43 characters) would need a = for padding. (seems you changed your comment and removed the / while or after I posted mine) (After all I can't really tell you, just wondered about your conclusion)

Yep I just figured that out, it is indeed base64 but without padding characters, I never noticed that / and the others were valid base64 character.

Turns out it is base64 but with padding characters removed.

It is not. There are many variants of base64, unfortunately, but when we say base64 without further qualification we usually mean this. What you are looking at is the Unix crypt hash format and that uses a different base64 variant called B64. This variant has no padding characters, uses "." instead of "+", and puts "." and "/" at the beginning of the alphabet rather than the end.

Is it specific to each hash algorithm (md5, sha, crypt, argon2)? Would you mind writing that as a response so that I can validate it ?
